# Android stream rtmp

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I want to stream rtmp from my android device, I search a lot in the web but I don't see anything except this url:

[Android Recorder](http://code.google.com/p/android-recorder/)
I downloaded it but I dont know how to use it and it haven't got any documentation.
Anybody knows how to use the libraries or have a sample code?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english!

PD:I'm trying to stream from my device not to my device.

Comment: That project doesn't have any files at all so wouldn't even know where to start from.

Comment: Ok! I found another proyect and it seems better: 
https://github.com/mogo29/Android-RTMP 
I think it can works.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Do you mind flagging this question for deletion if it's not relevant anymore? Ah, and welcome to SO ;)